# Move data from a cells in one worksheet to another if cell "C6" matches any of the ones in Row "2"

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I looking for advice/help with a piece of coding, I did something previously but that was based on the row name (cells in A) being the correct match, not the column, do you know if it possible, or if I am over complicating it.

Many thanks

K.Stevens

Pic 1 - Destination of where data is going to.

Pic 2 - Where the data is from.

```
 Sub Copy_Data()
 Dim hh As Worksheet, exist As Boolean, h As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
 Dim f As Range

 Set hh = Sheets("Form")
 If hh.Range("C5") = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please select the year", vbCritical
 Exit Sub
 End If
 If hh.Range("c6") = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please select the month", vbCritical
 Exit Sub
 End If
 exist = False
 For Each h In Sheets
 If LCase(h.Name) = LCase(hh.Range("c5").Value) Then
  Set sh = h
  exist = True
  Exit For
 End If
 Next
 If exist = False Then
 MsgBox "The sheet does not exist", vbCritical
 Exit Sub
 End If

 Set f = sh.Range("e2:p2").Find(hh.Range("C6").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
 If f Is Nothing Then
 MsgBox "The month cannot be found", vbCritical

  ---------Works up to this point --------

 Else
 'cell destination             cell origin
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "3").Value = hh.Range("C8").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "5").Value = hh.Range("c10").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "6").Value = hh.Range("C11").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "8").Value = hh.Range("C14").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "i").Value = hh.Range("C15").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "j").Value = hh.Range("C16").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "k").Value = hh.Range("C17").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "l").Value = hh.Range("C18").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "m").Value = hh.Range("C20").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "o").Value = hh.Range("C21").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "p").Value = hh.Range("C22").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "q").Value = hh.Range("C23").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "s").Value = hh.Range("C24").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "v").Value = hh.Range("C27").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "w").Value = hh.Range("C28").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "x").Value = hh.Range("C29").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "y").Value = hh.Range("C30").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "z").Value = hh.Range("C31").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ab").Value = hh.Range("C34").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ac").Value = hh.Range("C35").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ad").Value = hh.Range("C36").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "af").Value = hh.Range("C39").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ag").Value = hh.Range("C40").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ah").Value = hh.Range("C41").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "aj").Value = hh.Range("C44").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ak").Value = hh.Range("C45").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "al").Value = hh.Range("C46").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "am").Value = hh.Range("C47").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ar").Value = hh.Range("C50").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "as").Value = hh.Range("C51").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "at").Value = hh.Range("C52").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "aw").Value = hh.Range("C55").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ax").Value = hh.Range("C56").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "az").Value = hh.Range("C59").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "ba").Value = hh.Range("C60").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bb").Value = hh.Range("C61").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bc").Value = hh.Range("C62").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bd").Value = hh.Range("C63").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "be").Value = hh.Range("C64").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bf").Value = hh.Range("C65").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bg").Value = hh.Range("C66").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bh").Value = hh.Range("C67").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bi").Value = hh.Range("C68").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bj").Value = hh.Range("C69").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bk").Value = hh.Range("C70").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bm").Value = hh.Range("C73").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bn").Value = hh.Range("C74").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bo").Value = hh.Range("C75").Value
 sh.Cells(f.Column, "bp").Value = hh.Range("C76").Value

 End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a cell using Cells object:

> Cells(*row*, *column*)

where `row` must be an whole number (not a string containing an number) and `column` can be either a whole number or the column part of the cells address e.g. "BA" (53rd column)

So the following won't work:

```
sh.Cells(f.Column, "3").Value = hh.Range("C8").Value
```

But this would:

```
sh.Cells(f.Column, 3).Value = hh.Range("C8").Value
```

Or this:

```
sh.Cells(f.Column, "C").Value = hh.Range("C8").Value
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I had previously tried these ways and it still only copies them across the page not down the selected column. many thanks K

Comment: You're fixing which row you're writing to with `f.Column`. If you want to transpose the arrangement, swap your values - i.e. `sh.cells( 3, f.Column)`